# Why is my top border for span smaller than bottom one?

Tags: html, css

I want to have three triangles in a line where first and third are pointing up and middle one is pointing down. Now, First and Third (lower triangles) are okay, I am having trouble with middle one.

Why is the size of upper triangle so small?

How else can I have such an arrangement otherwise?

```css
.lower {
  border-width: 50px;
  border-color: black red green blue;
  border-style: solid;
}

.upper {
  border-width: 50px 50px 0 50px;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangles">
  <span class="lower"></span>
  <span class="upper"></span>
  <span class="lower"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As we all know span is an inline element so you have to make it an inline-block element to grab the actual space for span. Just add

```
span {
display: inline-block;
}
```

in CSS.
Border width problem will be fixed (Y).

Comment: What do you mean 'grab the actual space'? Also, please provide references.

Comment: Actually these are the basics of HTML & CSS. When we start leaning HTML we have to remember the tags and there type (inline or block). An inline element always takes space according to the given line height. So if you want to implement margin and padding properly on inline element you have make them inline-block or block.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is one part answer; alternative way of doing so. I still do not know why or how it happens.

```css
.lower,
.upper {
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

.lower {
  border-width: 0 50px 50px 50px;
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}

.upper {
  border-width: 50px 50px 0 50px;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangles">
  <span class="lower"></span>
  <span class="upper"></span>
  <span class="lower"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is due to the 0 in

```
border-width: 50px 50px 0 50px;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .lower {
      border-width: 50px;
      border-color: black red green blue;
      border-style: solid;
    }

    .upper {
      border-width: 50px 50px 0 50px;
      border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
      border-style: solid;
      height: 50px;
    }
    .disp {
      display: inline-flex;
    }
    <div class="triangles disp">
       <span class="lower"></span>
       <span class="upper"></span>
       <span class="lower"></span>
    </div>
```